# RAM usage increases when Activity called from Service multiple times

Tags: android, android-service

I have a problem here.
I have a Service which calls an activity to perform an action. The activity is called randomly or pre-defined time period.

But the RAM usage increases by 2-3 MB every time the activity is called.

This is how i call the activity from the Service,

```
         Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
         callIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
         callIntent.setClass(getBaseContext(),CustomDialog.class);
         startActivity(callIntent);
```

Comment: If the activity is not shown or used anymore Android will kill it and get ram that it is using when you will run low on RAM.

Comment: In case that it is used you need to kill it by calling onDestroy();

Comment: But even if i use onDestroy(), this does not solve the problem. RAM usage still increases by 2-3MB when activity is called multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, that is because you are creating new instances of your activity each time. Either use `FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT` instead of `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`, or make sure that your old activity instances get destroyed at some point (e.g., user pressing BACK or you calling `finish()`).

You are welcome to get a heap dump from DDMS, examine it in MAT, and determine specifically where your problem lies.

Comment: Thank you very much. FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK should be used for calling an activity from a service, otherwise got an runtimeexception error. But, finally found the solution by analyzing the heap dump. An custom text View was eating up my RAM space. Thank you.